# Check recipient email address with MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a question about the MFMailComposeViewController for sending an Email in an app. Is it possible to check the recipient adress before sending the email ?

I did not find any response so i think it's not possible..

If it's not possible, there is other solution ?

Comment: Check the recipient address against what? Do you mean "verify that it's an active address that will accept delivery of mail"?

Answer (score 1):

When you present the `MFMailComposeViewController` you lose complete control over it.

You can't do anything with it, neither get the "To" email address nor prevent the sending of the mail.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1):

> **Important**: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.